# Can one CSS page reference another?

Tags: css

Let's say I have css1.css and css2.css.
Just for the sake of keeping files organized and small on my file system / Source control I would like to split them up however in my content, I still want to use all the definitions in both files.

Rather than link reference both in my content page, can css1.css just make css2.css available.

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147500/is-it-possible-to-include-one-css-file-into-another

Comment: Beware @import, these stylesheets can't be cached by the browser and there frontend performance degrades

Comment: @dcaunt: Interesting, got a cite for that?

Comment: Hmm I was thinking of http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#csslink though the performance problem is actually that IE doesn't support progressive rendering in such a case. If I can't find a link I'll remove the comment

Comment: Well, the progressive rendering thing is good to know regardless. That's a useful link, thanks.

Comment: Looks like I was wrong - @imported sheets can be cached. Further research on link vs import at Steve Souders blog http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/04/09/dont-use-import/ He did a lot of the Yahoo! performance research

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearly you can include them all on your page with several  nodes, but your best bet is probably a release process script/ant task/automated build process which can concatenate or merge the files based on some manifest or even simply the order of the file names.

You can do other things like compress the css at the same time - automatically optimising files for deployment!

Answer (score 3):

Assuming both stylesheets are in the same directory, put this code at the top of css1.css.

```
@import url("css2.css");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use @import like this in css1.css:

```
@import url("css2.css");
p { color : #f00; }
```

Comment: i believe this is frowned upon if for no other reason than that imported CSS stylesheets have lower specificity which can cause unexpected bugs.

Comment: @Steven: Are you sure? The CSS 2.1 spec section on cascading (http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html) says this: "Declarations in imported style sheets are considered to be before any declarations in the style sheet itself." It doesn't say anything about `@import` affecting specificity.

Comment: i'm not entirely positive, but i think i've read that somewhere before.  I haven't been able to find it again so I guess you should consider it false until proven otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen that a lot; the import url("css2.css") feature so it is definitely a way to achieve your objective.