# Overload a CSS file from a gem in a Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, rubygems

I'm writing a Rails gem for my app. In this gem I have a CSS file. And everything works fine. But I want to be able to overload this file in my Rails app. Like this, my App will use the custom version of my CSS file.

Is it possible ?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I found it.

I created a file with the same name in my App, but it also need to be located in a directory with the exact same path.

In my case, I was trying to overload the file in my gem located vendor/assets/stylesheets with a file in app/assets/stylesheets

Answer (score 0):

You could also do a configuration option if the convention is too complex:

```
MyGem.configure do |config|
  config.stylesheet = 'app/stylesheets/my_style.css'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go with @import so that you are including stylesheets into other

[Is it possible to include one CSS file in another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147500/is-it-possible-to-include-one-css-file-into-another)