# CSS link stylesheets from stylesheet

Tags: css, stylesheet

The issue I'm having is that I need to add a second stylesheet to my web site. But I'd rather not update the 20+ HTML pages with a  code. Is there any way to link from the existing stylesheet to another? That way I only change one page? The second stylesheet is a font from Google Fonts. Any help would be great!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to include one css file into another?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147500/is-it-possible-to-include-one-css-file-into-another)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `@import` function in css. for example:

`@import url("YOUR_CSS_FILE.css");`

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can use @import. 
http://www.cssnewbie.com/css-import-rule/