# Http Proxy server for Android

Tags: android, http, proxy

I need to intercept http calls executed by a browser on an android device to automatically modify the header of the request and add javascript an css. 
On a browser running on a desktop this is usually possible implementing a plugin. Unfortunately browsers on androids do not have plugin mechanism.

What I was thinking to do is to configure the browser to access a local proxy server running on the device itself.

Do you think that this is possible?

If you think that this is off topic, could you please add a comment and tell me why?

Thanks

Comment: Try with https://github.com/adamfisk/LittleProxy. It seems compatible with Android even though some had issues.

Comment: Could you please tell me in what sense this question is about "recommending a book, tool, etc..." ? I am not asking for libraries but only if what I want to do is possible or not. I do not understand why my question is off-topic and the following question has more than 400 upvotes... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147500/is-it-possible-to-include-one-css-file-in-another