# How to make website multi-platform devices?

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver

I'm working with Macrowave Dreamweaver 8. I need to make display my website for all devices. I have an `index.css` witch contains desktop style, and an `index_mobile.css` that is the style sheet of mobile devices.

I used `display:none` to all `div` in `index_mobile.css` that aren't used on mobile version. Than in my `index.htm` i set:

```
@import url (LAYOUT/index.css);
@import url(LAYOUT/index_mobile.css);
```

but it didm't change nothing. What i missed?

Comment: Try bootstrap 3 http://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: I would start with reading something about [responsive web design](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/01/guidelines-for-responsive-web-design/), you can try something like [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/) or [Semantic UI](https://semantic-ui.com/)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The easiest and best way to do this is by using [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/). Take a look at the `container` `rows` and `columns`. Bootstrap is really easy to use and it will safe you a lot of time, it also comes with components that you can easily style by overwriting the bootstrap CSS with your own CSS.

Either use bootstrap 3 or the latest bootstrap 4 beta.

[Get started with Bootstrap 4 beta](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/)

Comment: @GianlucaCaliendo In that case try to use `@import url("LAYOUT/index.css");` you missed the ". For more information read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147500/is-it-possible-to-include-one-css-file-in-another)

Comment: @GianlucaCaliendo I think that you need something like this: `<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-device-width: 800px)" href="800.css" />` please read [this](https://css-tricks.com/resolution-specific-stylesheets/)

Comment: please help me to delete this question by delete your answer