# Import css from a file in shared module or node module in next js

Tags: webpack, next.js, postcss, css-modules

My setup:
I have a mono repo with multiple NextJS app sharing component from a shared module. The apps and shared module are individual workspaces managed by npm workspace. I m using css modules and post css for my NextJS apps.

Problem:
I want to import a css file from a shared module to css files in the NextJS apps. For example, I want to do something like `@import @shared/shared.css` in my css file for one of my component in the NextJS app.

Solutions tried:

1. postcss-import - works but its weird to import css files within the shared module components from shared modules using full package name. I hear relative path root can be specified using `from` but not really good doc.
2. tried something like `@import ~@shared/shared.css`. My IDE actually recognizes the path and is happy but the application fails to resolve the import and errors out like this: `error - ../node_modules/next/dist/compiled/css-loader/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[2].oneOf[2].use[1]!../node_modules/next/dist/compiled/postcss-loader/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[2].oneOf[2].use[2]!./components/common/ToastAlert/ToastAlert.module.css TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'file' of 'undefined' as it is undefined.`

Thank you in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Is it possible to include one CSS file in another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147500/is-it-possible-to-include-one-css-file-in-another)? Try importing it as `@import "@shared/shared.css";` in your CSS file.

Comment: hi @juliomalves. that does not solve my issue. The postcss-import solves it but i m trying to see if there is a better way without using that lib.

Comment: is there any way to import JS file from node modules?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [next-transpile-modules](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-transpile-modules) package. The way you use it

```
// next.config.js
const withTM = require("next-transpile-modules");
const nextConfig = {...}

module.exports = withTM(["@shared"])(nextConfig);
```

Worked for me with no issues. I used rush.